# Fixed background image held back by div height?

Tags: css

I load a background image through jquery into a DiV, and occasionally a modal pops up which stretches the screen height so that you have to scroll.

I wanted to have my bg image scroll with the view, but the issue is that `height:100%` apparently means 100% of the original height. The div doesn't stretch with the rest of the screen.

Why is that? Here is my code:

```
#bgDiv {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
        background-attachment:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your HTML (or a relevant portion of it), too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your position to fixed instead of absolute, it should stay, even when there is scrolling.